# Bitwise computation and count number of set bits afterward

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table:

```
create_table "fingerprint" do |t|
    t.bit "fp1", limit: 64
    t.bit "fp2", limit: 64
    t.bit "fp3", limit: 64
    t.bit "fp4", limit: 64
    t.bit "fp5", limit: 64
end

fp1 | fp2 | fp3 | fp4 | fp5
---------------------------
001 | 010 | 011 | 100 | 101
```

And an array of 5 elements

```
fp = [5,4,3,2,1]
```

I'd like and bitwise each record of the table with each element `fp` and then count the total number of set bits over 5 columns.

For example:

```
(001 & 5) = 001
(010 & 4) = 000
(011 & 3) = 011
(100 & 2) = 000
(101 & 1) = 001
Total number of set bits: 4
```

I want to loop this procedure in every row of my table. Please help me with an efficient way to do it (the table has about 100k rows).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What type are the columns?

Comment: Sorry, I  forgot this info. I  have updated the question, the column type is "bit(64)"

Comment: Your best approach depends on how serious you are when you want it to be "efficient".  Are you willing to create a plpgsql function or maybe a dynamically loaded c-language function?  How many times per day, hour, or minute will this query be run?

Comment: @NovaDenizen: this query will run on user request, and it will be run quite often. I haven't tried any of your suggestion. Every solution is welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example for the type `bit(3)`. You can easily adapt this for `bit(64)`:

```
create table the_table (fp1 bit(3), fp2 bit(3), fp3 bit(3), fp4 bit(3), fp5 bit(3));
insert into the_table values
('001', '010', '011', '100', '101'),
('101', '011', '111', '110', '101');

with the_array(arr) as (
    values (array[5,4,3,2,1])
),
new_values as (
    select 
        fp1 & arr[1]::bit(3) n1,
        fp2 & arr[2]::bit(3) n2,
        fp3 & arr[3]::bit(3) n3,
        fp4 & arr[4]::bit(3) n4,
        fp5 & arr[5]::bit(3) n5
    from the_table
    cross join the_array
)
select 
    *, 
    length(
        translate(
            concat(n1::text, n2::text, n3::text, n4::text, n5::text),
            '0',
            '')
    ) bit_set
from new_values;

 n1  | n2  | n3  | n4  | n5  | bit_set 
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------
 001 | 000 | 011 | 000 | 001 |       4
 101 | 000 | 011 | 010 | 001 |       6
(2 rows)
```

Comment: That's a bad use of WITH for new_values; it's going to needlessly materialize that entire result set.

Comment: @JimNasby - What is a better alternative?

Comment: @klin: Thank you for this example